# nginx: No client certificate CA names sent

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, openssl, self-signed-certificate

I have nginx and want it to verify client certificates. So I bought commercial certificate for server, and non-commercial for clients. Basically I've generated client certificates with easy-rsa scripts. Connecting with client certificates validation disabled works as expected. Connecting with "ssl_verify_client on;" fails with code 400 and no information in error or access log.

nginx -V outputs:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.8.0
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/nginx.lock --user=http --group=http --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=stderr --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/client-body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-imap --with-imap_ssl_module --with-ipv6 --with-pcre-jit --with-file-aio --with-http_dav_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_sub_module
```

my nginx config looks like this

```
server {
    listen                         my.addr.here:443 ssl;

    server_name                    my-server;

    ssl                            on;
    ssl_certificate                /etc/nginx/ssl/my-server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key            /etc/nginx/ssl/my-server.key;
    ssl_dhparam                    /etc/nginx/ssl/my-server.dhparam;
    ssl_protocols                  TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                    "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers      on;
    ssl_client_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/client-ca.crt;
    ssl_verify_client              optional;
    add_header                     X-Client-Certificate-Status $ssl_client_verify;

    # unrelated stuff here
}
```

when I test by OpenSSL client execuing it like this

```
openssl s_client -connect my-server:443 -cert client.crt -key client.key
```

I receive the following output

```
openssl s_client -connect my-server:443 -cert client.crt -key client.key
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Multi-Domain, CN = my-server
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain/CN=my-server
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 3 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain/CN=my-server
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGczCCBVugAwIBAgIRAO+Wb7x6RNHrhAhvUhGKg4EwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
................................................................

................................................................
/CEp3cHZNnU7JQbgq+r7R16oIONxthXGQQVjE36Bt9KS1ibpaIUThidUDCqzLYjn
IOKTJM0r8DVzO2leJDTnuDayOXCji/I=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain/CN=my-server
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 7198 bytes and written 474 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 727A........................................................1F7C
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 0019........................................................................................3CF8
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 0c 72 58 ce 43 33 3f 3f-aa e9 e1 e2 fa 9f 67 ae   .rX.C3??......g.
    .........................................................................

    .........................................................................
    00a0 - a4 14 27 fe 80 19 56 af-2d e6 f2 65 3b 0d cd e4   ..'...V.-..e;...

    Start Time: 1433018240
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Please, note "No client certificate CA names sent" string which as far as I understand means nginx is not properly configured to verify client certificates.

And when I issue request like this

```
GET https://my-server/robots.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: my-server
```

I get output like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 30 May 2015 20:37:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 103
Last-Modified: Sun, 12 Oct 2014 17:57:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "543ac105-67"
Expires: Sat, 30 May 2015 20:37:37 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Client-Certificate-Status: NONE
Accept-Ranges: bytes

User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Host: my-server
```

Please note "X-Client-Certificate-Status" equals to NONE, so $ssl_client_verify was NONE, so no validation takes place.

What can be the cause of this and what can I do to debug this issue?

Comment: Does your nginx `error_log` or other logging contain any messages/complaints about the configured `/etc/nginx/ssl/client-ca.crt` file?

Answer (score 5):

The reason was an error in nginx configuration, SSL options were specified twice.